# [ERROR] ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Есть две сущности:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Man extends Person {
    ...
}
```

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий метод:

```
@Test
public void clear(EntityManager em) {
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    System.out.println(em
            .createQuery("delete from Man m where m.id > 14582647")
            .executeUpdate());
    tx.commit();
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
[ERROR] ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

hibernate.show_sql показывает sql-запросы:

```
Hibernate: insert into HT_Man select man0_.id as id from Man man0_ inner join Person man0_1_ on man0_.id=man0_1_.id where id=14582647
Hibernate: delete from HT_Man
```

Ошибка возникает в месте `where id=14582647` т.к. тут должно быть не просто `id`, а например `man0_.id`. Как сделать так чтобы hibernate генерировал правильный sql-запрос?